# Linear curve fitting with prime coordinates.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Using this [Linear curve fitting](https://www.dcode.fr/function-equation-finder) with prime coordinates below, the equation generated is

$f(x)=x+8.28923$

```
x-axis          y-axis
------          ------
2               3
5               7  
11              13
17              19
23              29
31              37
41              43
47              53
59              61
67              71
73              79
83              89
1000003         1000033
1000037         1000039
1000081         1000099
1000117         1000121
1000133         1000151
1000159         1000171
1000183         1000187
1000193         1000199
100000007       100000037
100000039       100000049
100000073       100000081
100000123       100000127
100000193       100000213
1000000007      1000000009
1000000021      1000000033
1000000087      1000000093
```

[image: LINEAR]

**Question**

Since the equation of straight line is given by

$f(x)= ax + b$

I'm wondering how to interpret $b$?

From playing with various lists of prime coords, it seems to have this loose relation

$b \approx log(n)$

where $n$ is the largest prime coord.

Comment: $b$ should evolve like the average gap between consecutive primes. And this is indeed the case: this gap is equivalent to $\log(n)$. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime number theorem says $p_n \sim n\log n$. Hence

$$
p_{n+1} \sim (n+1)\log(n+1) = n \log(n+1) + \log(n+1) \sim n\log n + \log n
$$

So $a \sim b \sim \log n$.